Detect that an underlying TCP connection used by a HttpClient is closed
In a nutshell
My service is using a dotnet HttpClient in order to perform queries to other service. I would like to log something when the underlying TCP connection to that other service is closed. Is it possible, and how can I do that?
In more details: the problem I'm trying to solve
I'm seeing (on wireshark dumps) that it can happen that an underlying TCP connection used by my HttpClient is closed (that's the case when the idle timeout is reach). Then the subsequent query has some extra latency because a of the creation of the new TCP connection + SSL handshake.
It's cool to be able to reproduce it locally, What I'm trying to find out is how often this occurs when I receive real prod traffic (and subsequently monitor if I'm able to improve it). That's why I would like to be able to log something whenever this event (TCP connection is closed) occurs.

I don't think u can in a simple way.... because "closed" connection means different statuses at the low level connection like: CLOSE_WAIT, FIN_WAIT_1, TIME_WAIT...  This article may help you more: https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/dotnet-httpclient-basic-usage-scenarios/

You could initialize a static HttpClient instance with a custom SocketsHttpHandler (e.g., var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler() { // Config. } ; var client = new HttpClient(handler);). Configure the handler, setting its .ConnectCallback property to a method (or Lambda) that creates the Socket used to open the connections. You can use this Socket to poll the status of the connection, testing both the value returned by [Socket].Poll() and [Socket].Available == 0 (no bytes available to read) -- [Socket].Connected is not reliable (refers to the past operations)

thanks for your comments! That helped me derive a solution that appears to work just fine to solve my problem (that I just posted as an actual answer)

As hinted by some comments, I managed to solve my problem by tracking not the connections being closed, but the connections being opened, with this code:
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();


// The important part is the log line
// The rest of the implementation comes from the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.connectcallback?view=net-8.0#examples
handler.ConnectCallback = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.NoDelay = true;
    try
    {
        await socket.ConnectAsync(context.DnsEndPoint, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        _logger.Log("*** A connection is being created ***");
        return new NetworkStream(socket, true);
    }
    catch
    {
        socket.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
};

// other customization of the handler if needed. eg: handler.PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = ...

var client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false);

